# MVC 2 EF 4.0 Proper way to handle edits for something like products

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, edit

I have an exam on monday and i wanted to ask you if someone knows what would be the best way to handle edits in a ProductView for example.
More or less it's about the code within the ProductController.

Maybe someone knows a cleaner solutions than my two attemps.

This is the first way i did:

I have this in the get of my Edit

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var productToEdit = (from p in db.Products
                             where p.ProductId == id
                             select p).First();

        return View(productToEdit);

    }
```

This in the post of the Edit:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product productToEdit)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here
            var originalProducts = (from p in db.Products
                                    where p.ProductId == productToEdit.ProductId
                                    select p).First();

            db.ApplyCurrentValues(originalProducts.EntityKey.EntitySetName, productToEdit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Is this a good clean solution?

This would be the second solution i thought of:

[image]

The exam has to be done in MVC 2 with EF 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* do a catch-all `try` block. You risk swallowing all kinds of different exceptions, unrelated to the fact that the object doesn't exist in the DB.

Here, though, you really shouldn't even use a `try` block. There's only one use-case you're concerned with: not finding a match in the database, so it's preferable, use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` and then cover the `null`-value scenario:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Product productToEdit)
{
    var originalProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p.ProductId == id);
    if (originalProduct == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    // do update

    return View(productToEdit);
}
```

Notice a few things also:

1. The `id` param should still be passed. It's part of the URL and you should use that rather than what is posted to look up the right product. The posted value may be modified, but you can't change the `id` param in the URL without requesting an entirely different resource.
2. When returning a view on a post action, you need to pass the model that was posted. The only time you return a view here is if there's a validation error, and unless you pass the posted model, the user will not be able to update the existing values to fix those errors. Instead, they just have to start completely over.
3. I'm using Entity Framework querying syntax here. Although you *can* use LINQ to SQL syntax, it's more verbose, less readable, and non-standard.
4. I'm using `FirstOrDefault` rather than `First` for demonstrative purposes, but here it would actually make the most sense to just use `db.Products.Find(id)`.

Comment: So how would you pass the model in the `return View`? and you'd rather wirte `var originalProduct = db.Products.Find(id)` than how i did it?

Comment: It's right in the sample code above: `return View(productToEdit);`. And, yes, the LINQ to SQL syntax is an abomination and makes your code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

public ActionResult Get(int id) //Change the method name to get
    {
        var productToEdit = (from p in db.Products
                             where p.ProductId == id
                             select p).FirstOrDefault();  //always use firstordefault instead of first

```
    return View(productToEdit);

}
```

Use second approach.

Comment: Why second? Can you explain me more detailed what benefits i have from using second vs first?